# Combo box not showing in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, combobox

I'm trying to add a combo box in my WP8 app made with visual studio 2015.

I have code:

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
        <ComboBox x:Name="mycombo">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="52" Width="auto">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="nameblock" Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="41" Width="331" FontSize="30" Margin="10,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

in XAML and

```
List<Resultclass> mylist = new List<Resultclass>();
.
.
.
mycombo.ItemsSource = mylist;
```

in .cs file, and i can see items on screen, but they are shown as classic listbox, not as combo dropdown.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: The only thing I can think about is Grid, while I think should be StackLayout in this case. Also why you do bindings to List instead ObservableCollection?

Comment: Your description is not clear. I believe what you see is a option to select an item. When you click on it all the items appear on screen in regular listbox. Is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have declared the Resultclass like this

```
 public class Resultclass
        {
            public string name { set; get; }
            public Resultclass(string _name)
            {
                name = _name;
            }
        }
```

and added items:

```
 List<Resultclass> mylist = new List<Resultclass>();
            listData.Add(new Resultclass("item a"));
            listData.Add(new Resultclass("item b"));
            listData.Add(new Resultclass("item c"));
            mycombo.ItemsSource = mylist;
```